# Fill panorama item dynamically in wp7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I dynamically want to add panorama items in my application. No. of item(3 to 7) is depend on the json response I am getting. Presently for testing I created 4 items in xaml and it works for me but its not dynamic. Here is my xaml.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <controls:Panorama Title="my panorama" Loaded="Panorama_Loaded" Name="title1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <controls:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Panaroma_BG.png"/>
        </controls:Panorama.Background>

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item1" Name="dashboard1" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DashBoardName}">
            <Grid>
                <ListBox Height="512" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,8,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="403" Tap="listBox1_Tap">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Height="100" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        Height="132">
                                        <StackPanel Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="25" />
                                                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding SubImage}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PreviousValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15" />
                                            </Grid>
                                            <StackPanel Width="290" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="290" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
     <!--Panorama item two-->
     <!--Panorama item three-->
     <!--.................-->
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

I don't want to write xaml for Panorama item two, Panorama item three and so on I think there must be some way to do it at runtime. Please help me out.
There must be some template like thing which I can use. and then fill the inner items like `CurrentValue` , `ItemName` etc. through code

Answer (score 0):

I have tested below code for pivot. You can implement similar for Panaroma

```
Dim objPivotItem As PivotItem
Dim sScrollViewer As ScrollViewer
Dim sStackPanel As StackPanel
Dim textHeader As TextBlock
Dim txtContents As RichTextBox
For i = 0 to <Condition>

       objPivotItem = New PivotItem
       sStackPanel = New StackPanel
       sScrollViewer = New ScrollViewer
       textHeader = New TextBlock
       txtContents = New RichTextBox
'Set TextHeader properties
'Set TxtContents properties
objPivotItem.Content = sScrollViewer
sScrollViewer.Content = sStackPanel
sStackPanel.Children.Add(textHeader)
sStackPanel.Children.Add(txtContents)
objPivot.Items.Add(objPivotItem

)

Next i
```

Comment: I didn't get your solution, I think its not in c#.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can set an ItemsSource property for the whole panorama control, e. g.:

```
<phone:Panorama x:Name="MyPanorama">
        <phone:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <phone:PanoramaItem Header="MyHeader">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </phone:PanoramaItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
        <phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
    </phone:Panorama>
```

and then, for example from the code behind:

```
MyPanorama.ItemsSource = myItemsCollection;
```